# DC Motor causing photodiode emitter/detector into binary counter to malfunction

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, diodes, dc-motor, binary

Schematic shown below, except the resistor on the phototransistor is now 4k and I took out the PNP. The system is supposed to activate the motor on an up-down switch, forcing the first t flip flop positive. Then an 8 hole optical encoder on the DC motor shaft generates pulses groom the photo emitter/detector that is used for binary counting via 3 T flip flops. B2 runs through an OR gate with the switch so that when it goes back to 0 it forces Q1 to 0 and the motor stops. Essentially I want one full rotation for the DC motor with every switch toggle.

My binary counter works fine with the photo emitter/detector when I use a notecard to block the transmission. When I hook up the DC Motor the entire binary system starts going crazy, flickering lights, some stay on, some go off, always random. What can I do to prevent such noise?

Thanks. [image]

Comment: Motors are *very* noisy beasts. And you don't even have a flyback on it...

Comment: Do you have decoupling capacitors on your 5V rail? If yes, how many and what type? This sounds a lot like a problem with an unstable power supply.

Comment: Have you scoped the output of your circuit (input to the NPN base) while the motor's running? It would be useful to see if you're backfeeding big voltage spikes from the motor into the logic.

Comment: Didn't mean to submit previous comment so early... No capacitors being included. I am using AC to DC converter, 5V/4A. And don't have an oscilloscope to use currently but it's definitely sending voltage back somehow I'm guessing. At one point, my OR gate even got really hot!!

Comment: If you only need to spin in one direction I would put a freewheeling diode in parallel with the motor to deal with the inductive current spikes.

Comment: Have you tried putting a 100nF ceramic capacitor on the VCC/GND pins of all of your chips? Put them directly across the chips because distance matters - wires are inductive. Also put a single large-ish (~1000µF) capacitor on the 5V rail. Your problem is most likely noise on the 5V supply caused by the huge current spikes of the motor.

Comment: I haven't added any capacitors but I can try picking up some tomorrow morning and see what that does. I definitely think it's something with the 5V supply rail because even touching it with the motor causes lights to turn on sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to consider what is happening with your encoder.

[image]

As the slot moves across the path of the LED/Sensor it goes from covered to partially covered to fully uncovered and back. That means those edges are quite slow, and the slower the motor is moving the slower the edges. Worse, the motor can stop right at the mid-point.

While in that transition phase, any noise in the system, be it electrical or mechanical, will introduce extra counts on the clock pin of your counter.

There are a few things you can do to fix or improve that.

1. Make the holes as small as possible in your encoder disk with clean sharp edges.
2. Add a slot filter in front of the detector so light has to travel in a narrower beam to enter the sensor. (Shown in blue in the image above.)
3. Add a low pass filter to the sensor signal.
4. Add a buffer that Schmidt trigger buffer in the line so the signal has to cross the hysteresis threshold and keep the system "noise" under that threshold window.
5. Change your optical arrangement to add another sensor offset mechanically from the first one to produce a [quadrature](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/4763/en/) signal. This is ultimately the best solution since, with quadrature, things need to happen in a specific order and extra edges are of no consequence. It also lets you know which direction the motor/encoder is turning.

Comment: the problem right now though is that I'm running the motor without even including it in the photo sensor. Just by itself it is somehow changing my binary output.

Comment: @NLhere is the clock input floating?

Comment: Here is a picture of the actual circuit

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/vzlFZ

Comment: EEK... you are using a noise-board.. cough.. I mean bread-board.

Comment: The clock input is from the OR gate. Could it be something with how I converted JK's into T's? The Qs in my default setup are 1 but I reset them to 0 with the active low button.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I am. This is for a school project in mechatronics and I'm a mech engr major so I'm really struggling on diagnosing my error. Can you suggest a less noisy way of using a rotary optical encoder to force a DC motor through one rotation? I can't think of another way without using B2 looped back.

Comment: @NLhere unfortunately what you are doing is only half the solution. The inertia of the motor will likely cause you to travel farther than 1 rev. I am still convinced you are getting noise in the clock of that first counter stage though. Try moving the motor driver parts farther away and on their own power cables.

Comment: I purchased a 10rpm DC motor that I will eventually hook up that has a gear box on it so the inertia effects shouldn't be too much of a problem. I think you are right too, sometimes when I just randomly connect the motor to a rail it will turn on a light, I've rebuilt this like 5 times though and have no idea what's wrong, it's so frustrating.

Comment: @NLhere Disconnect the counter clock input from the sensor and tie it to ground. Then power it up and make it run the motor. If the counter behaved you KNOW it's coming from that sensor input. At that point, add in a Schmidt trigger.. 74xx17 into the sensor line. BTW: getting slot sensors to work right is challenging for all of us.

Comment: Connected binary counter to ground and then ran the motor just from a high rail to low rail and this is happening: https://youtu.be/4DjVYtA4tcw