# DC motor single rotation using Photodiode-transistor

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, diodes, dc-motor, binary

I am trying to build a system where a switch toggle (up then down) will cause a dc motor to do one full rotation and stop until the switch is flipped again. The only other input allowed is a hard reset button.

This is an analog circuit on a breadboard. I have rebuilt the same system about 5-10 times no and can't get it to work so I was hoping for some suggestions on a less noisy system. The previous system worked perfect for binary counting WITHOUT the motor connected, but as soon as I connected the motor I got tons of noise. Needs to be done with a binary counter. Below is my first try. I took out the PNP and put a 4k instead of 220 on the photo emitter. Also, I am going to be using a dc motor with a 10rpm gearbox. [image]

Comment: How is this different from the question [you have asked previously](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/166842/nlhere)?

Comment: Because I'm open to rebuilding a new system instead of adjusting my previous.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DC Motor causing photodiode emitter/detector into binary counter to malfunction](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/336494/dc-motor-causing-photodiode-emitter-detector-into-binary-counter-to-malfunction)

Comment: What is the part number of your flip-flops?  The suitable input circuit from your photo-detector may vary depending on the logic family you use.

Comment: They are 74LS107N, and the Phototransistor optical interrupter switch is H21A

Comment: Where are your [decoupling capacitors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoupling_capacitor)?

Comment: I don't have any capacitors in my circuit currently. My professor acted like they weren't necessary to accomplish the goal of this project. I'm trying to think of another way to re-do this entire system over but I don't know another way to use the optical encoder to control DC motor.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **do not edit and remove** your question. It is the 2nd time I see you do this. There is no need to say thanks, if you cannot resist, **use the comments**. Your question is now useless because the question is gone. I want you to learn how to use this site properly.

Comment: "I don't have any capacitors in my circuit currently. My professor acted like they weren't necessary" - 'acted like'? You have a motor producing electrical noise, clocked digital logic - you need good supply decoupling to eliminate glitches.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Actually was one of the only people to include capacitors on my breadboard. Got it working using 3 10 uF capacitors and then one 100nF across the motor terminals. The rest were able to get everything working so I might have just had things setup wrongly on the breadboard itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution since I know how frustrated you are getting.

You could always ditch the electronics and go old school with a cam, two limit micro-switches and a relay.

[image]

The top switch opens when the cam is home, so is normally closed while the motor is turning. The bottom switch opens briefly when the motor has turned the shaft 180 degrees.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feKN3Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Pressing the button closes the relay. The second pole of the relay bypasses the home switch to power the motor. Motor will advance and close the top switch keeping it running till the switch opens again.

The second pole of the relay pulls the relay coil low through the other micro-switch. That keeps the relay activated when you release the button. When the motor makes half a turn the second micro-switch will open briefly, releasing the relay. However, at that point, the motor will still be powered through the top micro-switch.

I also added a fly-back diode to the motor and a snubber circuit to limit the sparks and noise and make the relay last longer.

Old school I know, but I also know you are a "mechy" and can probably appreciate it more. Plus I know you will do a good job with the cam mechanics :)

BTW: If the motor inertia is too high for it to stop in time with the switch, you may want to consider adding a solenoid pin stop to the cam. You could drive that in parallel with the relay coil.

Comment: I WISH I could do it this way! Unfortunately I'm required to use a photo sensor and rotary optical encoder. I called into work, I'm determined to take this beast down but you are 100%right, I'm about to pull my hair out over this.

Comment: @NLhere dang.. I like simple answers like this. Sorry I can't help you more. You really need hands on help.

Comment: @@Trevor Hey Trevor I ended up using 3 10uF capacitors across the top rails and then a 100nF capacitor across the motor terminals. Just to be safe I also ran a separate 9V battery to the motor and all the noise was mitigated. Thank you for taking the time to explain things and offer suggestions

Answer (score 0):

[image]

*Figure 1. This won't work.*

- Remove the diode and PNP transistor.
- Connect the right side of the motor directly to the V+.

Comment: I have done this and it causes all of my binary counters to flicker or light up (does this with or without PNP& diode).

Comment: (1) Is the PSU capable of driving the motor? (2) If you connect the NPN 1k resistor to +5 instead of Q1 does the motor run? (3) If it does run does the supply dip on start? If your circuit flickers or resets then power is your problem.

Comment: If I connect the npn to 5V then it runs the motor and nothing flickers. There photo emitter/detector seems very sensitive but if I isolate the light it also will do the binary counting sequence accurately.

Comment: OK. Sorry I can't help you further.